Did Davy Jones and Salazar know of each other?
I watched a Pirates of the Caribbean marathon and I'm curious if it's explained anywhere whether captain Salazar and Davy Jones knew each other? Did they even have a war against each other or ever strike a deal or have any connection?

AFAIK, they did not have any interaction, but Salazaar should've known Davy Jones, since Jones is known by every sailor. and his Kraken. Since Salazaar was human on his voyage, he couldn't be able to do anything against Jones IMHO.
